# How to pass *args in vectorized function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

For the usual `*args` technique in python, but the function is `np.vectorized`. Normally, `*args` would work, but when I've vectorized the function and the args are a vector, it thinks the all the rows combined are the arguments rather than each row being the argument. I can obviously have `my_function(a,b,c,d,e)`, but my actual function has many many inputs. How do I do this with the `*args` technique?

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(50,1)
b = np.random.rand(50,1)

args = np.random.rand(50,3)

def my_function(a,b,c,d,e):
    
    result = a * b * c * d * e
    

    return result


my_func_vec = np.vectorize(my_function)
res = my_func_vec(a,b,*args)

# TypeError: my_function() takes 5 positional arguments but 52 were given
```

Comment: Don't forget `np.vectorize` does not promise performance.  Use it when your function takes scalar arguments, and you want to pass arrays that broadcast against each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `*args` will unpack `args` along the rows. You want to do it along the columns, so you can transpose first.

```py
my_func_vec(a, b, *args.T)
```

But this example doesn't require `np.vectorize`, and you should reexamine your actual case to see if it needs it. The code is much faster without it.

```py
%timeit my_function(a, b, *args.T)
14.8 µs ± 490 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit my_func_vec(a, b, *args.T)
468 µs ± 13.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(50, 1)
b = np.random.rand(50, 1)

args = np.random.rand(50,3)
    
def my_function(a, b, c, d, e):
    result = a * b * c * d * e
    return result

def wrapper_func(a, b, params_row):
    return my_function(a, b, *params_row)
my_func_vec = np.vectorize(wrapper_func, signature='(),(),(n)->()')


res = my_func_vec(np.squeeze(a), np.squeeze(b), args)  #to convert (50,1) arrays to (50,) to make things compatible 
print(res)
```

Output :

```
[2.04426871e-02 6.90251979e-03 3.65811647e-02 1.64784141e-04
 4.35888426e-02 1.11680236e-03 1.77265850e-02 4.95765052e-03
 6.79152250e-05 2.40806056e-04 5.21195880e-02 1.87644160e-02
 6.10992452e-04 4.10024255e-02 5.92372496e-03 2.90534846e-02
 2.46944495e-05 2.59179190e-02 1.21266065e-02 1.77476896e-01
 9.10771238e-03 1.79067184e-03 4.19752913e-01 1.67823828e-03
 3.63713035e-02 1.27287054e-02 9.40996439e-03 8.96187745e-03
 1.56632220e-04 3.19315171e-02 4.25328030e-03 5.83103313e-03
 4.89234139e-04 8.43781021e-04 4.80337136e-04 1.90698892e-01
 2.51064668e-04 7.27973431e-02 4.58804875e-03 1.09680786e-03
 6.62614160e-02 1.38636845e-04 5.13097091e-04 3.91293968e-04
 3.93461614e-03 6.66755401e-02 1.84588850e-04 7.37273682e-02
 1.28312385e-04 1.85730481e-03]
```

Here thing is (50,1) is not compatible with your params part. And to bring them together the wrapper function is present which can be take out but then signature will be different for ease creating a function to format is the better choice.

Comment: This anwer is correct - note that you could also `my_func_vec(a, b, args[:, 0], args[:, 1], args[:, 2])` - but that would be a bad idea, since it effectively unpacks `args` into three separate arrays and goes against the whole idea of vectorisation here.